How can I pass a float variable from Python to Wolfram Kernel?
I want to do something like this:
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr
session = WolframLanguageSession()

a = 1e20
session.evaluate(wlexpr(f"NIntegrate[x,{{x,0,{a}}}]"))

But in Python, str(1e20) is "1e+20" which can not be recognized by Wolfram. If I cannot use f-string or str to pass a float number, what should I do?

I believe the recommended way in such case is to use wolframclient.serializers.export. However, you can generally avoid any string conversion by typing in Mathematica expressions as pure python objects/functions.
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr
from wolframclient.serializers import export

session = WolframLanguageSession()

# Method 1
a = 1e20
session.evaluate(wl.NIntegrate(wl.x, [wl.x, 0, a]))

# Method 2
a = export(1e20).decode()
session.evaluate(wlexpr(f"NIntegrate[x,{{x,0,{a}}}]"))


For method 1 you actually don't need the export :) .

@xzczd, oh, right, of course, thanks! :)

Well, I'd argue this is actually a python question about string formatting. Related discussion in meta:
Are questions about calling Mathematica in other languages/softwares on-topic?
Anyway, according to e.g. this post:
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession

from numpy import format_float_positional as myform 

session = WolframLanguageSession()

a = 1e20
session.evaluate(f"NIntegrate[x,{{x,0,{myform(a)}}}]")

But, if you just want to pass argument(s), why not define a function?:
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession

session = WolframLanguageSession()

a = 1e20
func=session.function("NIntegrate[x, {x, 0, #}]&")
func(a)


Thanks for your answer! I didn’t know this format_float_positional function before. In fact, I wrote a similar function myself to do this. But I think this method is too ugly, because each variable needs to be covered with an extra function. Maybe I could map(format_func,my_variables), but that doesn't seem very pretty either.

@HaoenZhang See my update.
